# Laravel scheduler is not running automatically

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, laravel-artisan

I have made a scheduler. When I call it with `php artisan userRanking` it works.

This is the code in `Kernel.php`:

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\UserRanking::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('userRanking')
             ->everyMinute();
}
```

How do I dispatch it so that it runs automatically?

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you add  * * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to set up a single `cron` job that calls the schedule runner every minute:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Read [Laravel's Scheduler docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#introduction) for more info.

Comment: how to set this cron job and where exactly ?

Comment: @user2099451 - there are tons of tutorials on the web for that. [Here's one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/).

Comment: I dont want to start a new topic but Im new and nothing makes sense: I see "everyMinute()", so why do I need to run a cron job to execute a function that does things every minute?

Comment: @Sylar task won't run automatically, for that you need to set up cron which will execute your task every minute automatically

Comment: @Sylar to be clear, the cron starts "laravel" scheduler every minute. That scheduler will check upon each run, every minute, and see what schedules you have created and needs to be run that minute. Without the system cron/scheduler running laravel every minute, there would be nothing to start your scheduled command. The laravel scheduler does not start and stay running; it starts, checks, and closes.

Comment: @JosephSilber, I executed command `php artisan schedule:run` but only one time my command is executed. But I expected it to run every minute. What should I do?

Comment: @ParisaN you have the set the cron job like in the answer you're commenting on.

Comment: to avoid running the cron each minute, one can create a artian command and tag it to the cron job eg:- <code>0 0 * * * cd /home/user/sitepath && php artisan calculate:daily</code>