# Test scheduler in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have the following code snippet from `App/Console/Kernel.php` task scheduling:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $tours = Tour::all();
        $date =  date("Y/m/d");
        $week = strtotime("+1 week", $date);
        $exploded = explode("/", $week);

        foreach ($tours as $tour) {
            foreach($tour->datePrice as $d) {
                if ($d->isNotEmpty()) {
                    DB::table('dateprice')
                        ->where('tour_id', '=', $tour->id)
                        ->where('start_day', '=', $explode[0])
                        ->where('start_month', '=', $explode[1])
                        ->where('start_year', '=', $explode[2])
                        ->delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

I'm trying to delete records from table with the help of scheduler by checking start dates of a tour.
I'm running this schedule every minute to check whether it is working or not. With a wrecked luck the code isn't doing anything. Is there is any error in my code ??

I would be very thankful if anyone could let me know how to test scheduler in laravel.

Comment: did you execute schedule:run artisan command?

Comment: No, I didn't run the command. Do I need to run it daily or once ?

Comment: You need to run it every minute by cron jobs, read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel scheduler is not running automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993033/laravel-scheduler-is-not-running-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

you only need to add the following **Cron** entry to your server, it will automatically execute schedule:run artisan command.

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Use the following command to start **task scheduling**-

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

This command will stop working when you close the **cmd**

You can follow laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction).

Comment: Is there a way to test scheduler ??

Comment: php artisan schedule:run

Comment: I had a problem testing my scheduler in Laravel too. I could not see why it was not working so I created a log file in the dev folder. I saw that Artisan was getting Permission denied. So I had to change the permission for my artisan file and it started working. hope that helps